# Problem with Electron Installer and Auto Updater (Error Code 2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a problem well I created myself a very simple electron app based on this article [https://medium.com/@johndyer24/creating-and-deploying-an-auto-updating-electron-app-for-mac-and-windows-using-electron-builder-6a3982c0cee6](https://stackoverflow.com) except for what is included in this article I just don't have the signed apliactions.

I install the app on Windows (it installs in programdata), bump up the version and do deploy the update information on Windows shows up, it downloads, but during the installation there is a problem and a message pops up saying "Cannot delete old application files and code 2" in addition I checked the files in programdata and some are "read only".

I've been struggling with this problem for several days and can't find a solution ....

Electron autoupdater Cannot delete old application files and code 2...

**EDIT (add_code)**
https://gist.github.com/dudinio/88eee5c4483979b49da043500ee9caf5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added after edit in post  :)